# Limiting number of items to display per page

Tags: php, html

I have files like (for an instance ) being shown as shown in

http://lawcommission.gov.np/site/NepalLawCommissionFinal/NepalLawCommissionFinal/document.php?cat=112&sub_cat=10008

The document.php has following html to display the files:

```
            <section class="three-fourth">
                <div class="sort-by">
                    <h3>Sort by</h3>
                    <ul class="sort">
                        <li>Date <a href="#" title="ascending" class="ascending">ascending</a><a href="#" title="descending" class="descending">descending</a></li>
                        <li>Name <a href="#" title="ascending" class="ascending">ascending</a><a href="#" title="descending" class="descending">descending</a></li>
                        <li>Category <a href="#" title="ascending" class="ascending">ascending</a><a href="#" title="descending" class="descending">descending</a></li>

                    </ul>

                    <ul class="view-type">
                        <li class="grid-view"><a href="#" title="grid view">grid view</a></li>
                        <li class="list-view"><a href="#" title="list view">list view</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="deals clearfix">
                    <!--deal-->


                    <?php
                        $id = $_GET['cat'];



                        $base_obj = new Base();
                        $lst = $base_obj->list_doc($id);
                        $lst->execute();

                        foreach ($lst as $rec)
                        {
                            $sub_head = $rec['Head_Id'];
                            $get_sub = $base_obj->list_by_id('Head_Id', $sub_head, 'tbl_heading');
                            $get_sub->execute();
                            foreach ($get_sub as $h)
                            {
                                $heading = $h['Head_Name'];
                            }

                    ?>




                    <article class="one-fourth">
                        <figure><span style="float:left"><a href="hotel.html" title=""><img src="images/uploads/london1.jpg" alt="" style="width:100px" /></a></span><span style="float:left"><a href="#" title="Book now" class="gradient-button-green"></a></span></figure>

                        <div class="details">
                            <h1><?=$rec['Doc_Name'];?></h1>
                            <span class="address"><?=$heading;?></span>

                            <span class="price">Added On  <em><?=substr($rec['Uploaded_Date_Time'],0,10);?></em> </span>

                            <a href="<?=substr($rec['Doc_Location'],3);?>" title="Book now" class="gradient-button">Download</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <!--//deal-->
                    <?php 
                    } ?>


                    <!--bottom navigation-->
                    <div class="bottom-nav">
                        <!--back up button-->
                        <a href="#" class="scroll-to-top" title="Back up">Back up</a> 
                        <!--//back up button-->

                        <!--pager-->
                        <div class="pager">
                            <span><a href="#">First page</a></span>
                            <span><a href="#">&lt;</a></span>
                            <span class="current">1</span>
                            <span><a href="#">2</a></span>
                            <span><a href="#">3</a></span>
                            <span><a href="#">4</a></span>
                            <span><a href="#">5</a></span>
                            <span><a href="#">6</a></span>
                            <span><a href="#">7</a></span>
                            <span><a href="#">8</a></span>
                            <span><a href="#">&gt;</a></span>
                            <span><a href="#">Last page</a></span>
                        </div>
                        <!--//pager-->
                    </div>
                    <!--//bottom navigation-->
                </div>
            </section>
        <!--//three-fourth content-->
    </div>
    <!--//main content-->
</div>
<div class="wrap clearfix">



    <!--info boxes--><!--//info boxes-->
</div>
```

Can you guys please suggest a way to show only limited no. of pdf files in one page?

Comment: add `limit #` into `list_doc` function

Comment: @Lashane But it will leave out remaining file, is there a way to append the remaining files in page 2 , 3 and so on ?

Comment: yes, you can use `limit offset, count` and pass page number to this function

Comment: @Lashane Here is my list_doc function:
can you also suggest a way ?
           
public function list_doc($cat)
 {
  $qry=$this->dbobj->db1->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_documents, tbl_cat_head_doc WHERE tbl_cat_head_doc.Cat_Id = '$cat' AND tbl_cat_head_doc.Doc_Id = tbl_documents.Doc_Id AND tbl_documents.Status = 'a' ");
  return $qry;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you need to change your function:

```
public function list_doc($cat, $page=0) {
    $itemsPerPage = 20;
    $cat = intval($cat, 10);
    $start = intval($page, 10) * $itemsPerPage;
    if ($start < 0) $start = 0;

    $qry = $this->dbobj->db1->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
        FROM tbl_documents, tbl_cat_head_doc
        WHERE tbl_cat_head_doc.Cat_Id = " . $cat ." AND
        tbl_cat_head_doc.Doc_Id = tbl_documents.Doc_Id AND
        tbl_documents.Status = 'a'
        limit " . $start . "," . $itemsPerPage);
    return $qry;
}
```

and in main page call function like this:

```
$lst = $base_obj->list_doc($id, $_GET['page']);
```

to prevent next question: read about [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)